# unable to open product from Magento Backend, It is showing fatal error

Tags: magento

Error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getConfig() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content.php on line 50

Fatal Error on product page in frontend:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMediaUrl() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php on line 1018

Comment: Did you make changes in Magento Core? Edit your question and paste both methods where you have error

Comment: Mention out the changes you did, that would help us to understand the exact issue.

Comment: I didnt make any changes in magento core. i had just install magento 1.9 version and import my old website database. After that when i am login into my backend account and trying to open Product which are already created, it show me error: 

Fatal error: Call to a member function getConfig() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content.php on line 50, 

You can see Error Image Here: http://oi58.tinypic.com/zssi0n.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I really bet your issue is in your .gitignore.  I recently had the same issue, and it was because my .gitignore had media/ as one of the entries.
Well, go figure, that burried deep in the core inside Adminhtml is this path:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/
That gitignore was excluding that folder NOT just the main media folder in the root of the Magento installation.
Check your code base, I imagine that the folder is missing in your remote server.
Once you update your .gitignore that should be added and of course once you commit your code and pull it on the remote server, things will work as expected.
I changed my gitingore to be more specific here is the parts with the media folders
media/catalog/
media/customer/
media/dhl/
media/xmlconnect/

Comment: I have added my .gitignore file
var/*
includes/*
media/catalog/
media/customer/ 
media/dhl/ 
media/xmlconnect/
media/*
And reinstall my magento but, Still I am having same problem.
Plz specify what i have to change in my .gitignore file or entire folder to resolve that problem.
Thanks

Comment: Here is my generic .gitignore media/catalog/
media/customer/
media/dhl/
media/xmlconnect/
.htaccess
app/etc/local.xml
.sass-cache/
.idea/
.phpstorm.meta.php
.DS_Store
test.php
var/

Answer (score 0):

Error  `Call to a member function getConfig() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content.php on line 50` 
is caused by missing file Uploader.php located at

**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/** in most cases.

For example, if you migrate from one host to another this file may be lost

due to restrictions in access rights, I mean reading this file is not allowed
for everyone. It allowed only for owner of the file and members of the group of owner.

Comment: Don't you mean Uploader.php? Adding Uploader.php didn't help me anyway.

Comment: Yes, Vladimir, well spotted _Uploader.php_ not Upload.php.
Thanks!
This file in right place fix subject error in my case.
Did you place it at _app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/_ ?

Comment: It is worth to try flush all types of cache in Magento after you move Uploader.php to target path.

Comment: I added Media folder. It turns out this folder was cut out of git because of an incorrect .gitignore entry "media" which, in conjunction with case ignore being set to false effectively excluded this folder from git, along with the media folder which contains images, and stays in the root of the website. These folders are completely different and have different purpose, and are in different locations, but git sees them as same, being set like this (with case ignore and without slashes to indicate the position in the directory hierarchy). However, the problem stays.

Comment: I added only Uploader.php from  original distribution tarball/zip archive, which I  dowloaded from Magento site, not cloning from git repo or something else. This solve my problem.

Comment: I did this. I added the original file, and after that original whole directory (Media). Nothing worked. I am getting Invalid block type: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader in a log.

Comment: You can try restore original files from the "stock" tarball and use [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/maven-html5-uploader.html) extension

Answer (score 0):

This is one suggestion on what you should check. Follow these steps:

1.Check your version of Magento (for example, go to admin, scroll to the bottom ad see the version number).
2.Find this Magento version on the web and download it.
3.Copy over the app/code/core directory, overwrite the existing directory.
4.If you pulled file system from git, then don't overwrite anything while you are working on the steps one through three
5.Try again to access the product.

Which Magento version are you using, which PHP version? Which Operating System?